# p(R|Q) = p(R|P ∧ Q) if and only if P, Q and R are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've been told that p(R|Q) = p(R|P ∧ Q) if and only if P, R and Q are independent, but I can't see why this is the case. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: This is not true, e.g., take the case $P=Q=R$, with probability $p\in(0,1)$.

Comment: This is actually related to a looser condition known as conditional independence, where this is true iff P and R are conditionally independent given Q. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence